# how to get rid of the space appears before the css transition and make the image appear in full

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two concerns:

1) When resize the window to mobile screen,there's a space appears on the left. why it happens and how to get rid of it? Now you won't see white space coz I used `background-repeat:repeat;` so the background image will cover it.Yet I don't want that.

2) The transition should stop when the full image loaded (until you see the bridge).But in mobile view it doesn't show the full image!

here's the link: http://vani.valse.com.my/beldon/

Thanks a lot!

HTML

```
<div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12  columns home cover">

               <div id="target">
                 <div class="small-12 medium-11 large-11 columns text2">
                 Beyond Law,<br/>
                 The Spirit of Innovation is Our strenght.
                 </div>
               </div>


             </div>

             <div style="clear: both"></div>
```

css

```
.cover
{width: 100%;
 z-index:2000; 
 position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 5%;}

#target {
    position: relative;
    left:0;
    background-image:url('../img/top-bg.jpg');
    background-color:#365859;
    width: 120%;


    background-size:cover;
    height: 600px;  
    background-position: 200px 50%;
    transition: background-position 2s ease-in-out;
  /*to move the image slowly*/
    transition-duration:4s;
}


#target.wide{
    left: -20%;
    padding-left: 30%;
   background-position: 0px 50%;

}
```

Script

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#target').toggleClass("wide");

    });

   </script>
```

Comment: Im not quite sure what your goal is here. The link provided just says "left" and "right".

Comment: @cpk sorry for the confusion.. this is the correct link: http://vani.valse.com.my/beldon/

Comment: @cpk please resize the link  to mobile size then you will notice background repeats on the left for the banner.if I remove background-repeat there will be white space.How to remove that?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. It only happens on page load for me. Maybe try:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #target {
        transition: none;
        -moz-transition: none;
    }
}
```

It moves to the correct place, but the transition looks off when you first load the page.

Comment: did this answer your question? If so, mark as the accepted answer by clicking the check. If not,  let's figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. Im still a bit unsure of what you are trying to accomplish. Maybe make a codepen?

Comment: @cpk....here u go..http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYXmOQ  . U see the background repeated on the left,I want to avoid that..But i remove background-repeat,white space will appear.I want to get rid of that.

Comment: It is still unclear. You are trying to perform a background-position: transition on the child div, but this will expose the parent div behind it, so you will have to decide what you want the background on the parent to be.   Experiment with placing the image as the background on the parent div